# How to correctly use the new Create Guide Index Map node in blender 3.5

Tags: particles, geometry-nodes, hair

I am trying to figure out how to use this node as shown in the example video. Ideally I want to be able to output values as shown, based on strand proximity to my guides.
[image: example screenshot from documentation]

My initial attempt was to try and drag the node setup onto the hair system modifier stack, and use the attribute "guide_curve_index" output in my material, but this doesn't appear to produce any usable values.
[image: my attempt]
link to the documentation page here: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.5/modeling/geometry_nodes/hair/guides/create_guide_index_map.html

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The GN *"Interpolate Hair Curves"* already outputs "guide_curve_index". Do you want to overwrite this attribute?

Comment: ah. hmm I wasn't aware it outputs already from a different  node. I will try that. Basically I want values on the hair that I can assign colors to in the shader nodes, the strand values should be unique based on proximity to the guide curves.

Comment: I didn't know that this was also mentioned in the documentation and just became aware that the second sentence in your screenshot describes exactly that: Other hair nodes use this node internally. Meanwhile I've found the video and now I understand what you meant by *"as shown in the example video"* :D . You want to colour the hair strands. Ok, that's easy, apart from a few pitfalls.

Comment: yup. exactly. sorry for my long-winded explanation. any light shed on how you would go about it would be most helpful. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** This is not an exact answer to the question in the title how to use the *Create Guide Index Map* node group. Instead, it shows how to use the resulting *guide_curve_index* attribute to colour hair, which is the actual goal of the questioner.

---

If you just want to colorize the strands you can use the *guide_curve_index* attribute. It is created by the geometry node modifier *Interpolate Hair Curves* and *Duplicate Hair Curves* created by the assets of the same name. And it's internally used by other hair assets like *Curl Hair Curves*, *Braid Hair Curves*, *Clump Hair Curves*, etc.

Note that the *guide_curve_index* (=sculpted hair) will be discarded and replaced when you uncheck the option *[_] Existing Guide Map* option in these modifiers. They use the *Create Guide Index Map* node group internally to create a new *guide_curve_index* attribute. The name of this attribute is hard-coded in the node group. However, it is also output and can be stored in another attribute.

The values are index numbers of hair guides. Depending on how the guides were created<sup>**(1)**</sup>, the index values may vary. For example: 7, 3, 12, 50, 1954, 1935. Keep in mind that it is not certain that the values are continuous, ordered, equally distributed or have a specific minimum or maximum value.

You still can use these "random" index values to create colorized strands. A *Color Ramp* node takes values from 0 to 1 for the *Fac* input. To map the index values of the *guide_curve_index* attribute you can use the node *White Noise* node with one dimension (1D) as a kind of hash function. This converts a value ("W") to another value ("Value"), which is always between 0 and 1 and it's always the same output for the certain input value. 
This way you can input a given number (the curve guide index) and you will get a "random" number between 0 and 1. (If you need more control or randomness you can use the 4D option and change the input *Vector* value.) Finally this is the input for the *Color Ramp*:

[image: colorized strands]

---

**(1)** Side note: It looks like the *Interpolate Hair Curves* node group adds a value to the Spline ID when *Part by Mesh Islands* is checked/unchecked. (The added value can be 0. I have no idea what is done there and what "*Part by Mesh Islands*" exactly does. The node group is scary huge!). It is therefore not guaranteed that you will always receive the true index (=ID) of the sculpted hair guides in the attribute *guide_curve_index* but often you get them in an ordered form like  0, 1, 2, 3, ...

[image: interpolate hair curves internal stuff]

Comment: Thank you for the incredibly detailed answer! Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for taking the time to write this. (By the way, I believe the "part by mesh islands" is used to prevent children strands from interpolating across mesh chunks that have been split apart, highly useful for creating neat parting on a character's hairstyle by simply splitting the scalp mesh in the center, etc. )